# How do I add a link to an open graph action on a profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I created an open graph action which works on a profile. this create a post in this form

```
{User 1} {action} {User 2} in {my application}
```

The problem is that when I click on the post image or the users' name I am redirected to the user's profile. I need to redirect the user to our application's homepage. How can I add the link to our homepage?

Clarification: I want {user 2} to get a notification that the action was performed and to post it on his wall.

Comment: Are you referring to clicking on `{User 1}` or `{User 2}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect users to your homepage when someone clicks on {User 2} or on the image for that action, your best bet is to create a custom page (separate from the user's profile on your site) that will detect if the User Agent is Facebook or a general user.  Set that page as the url for your Open Graph object.

Facebook will get its data and you will redirect users to the homepage. For instance:

```
if request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == 'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)'
  render :profile_tags # you just need to show the open graph tags
else
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you link to the user in your action, Facebook will bring clicks of that user's name to the user's profile - this is expected behaviour.

If you don't want that, don't link to the user's facebook profile, link to a custom object in your app which represents that user's activity/profile in your app

Comment: I can do that but I also want a post on user's wall and a Facebook notification for that user